# jquery/ajax delete function keeps refreshing instead of animation

Tags: jquery, ajax

***SOLVED***: there is still no animation, tough the unwanted page refresh is gone, and for now on i can continue...

The script works, it actually deletes the records from the mySQL db
Tough instead of the fading animation, the page just refreshes...
i'm using jquery-2.2.0.min.js

jquery/ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".delete").click(function(){
        var element = $(this);
        var sht_id = element.attr("id");
        var info = 'id=' + sht_id;
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'delsht.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: info,
                succes: function() {

                }
            });
            $(this).parent().parent().fadeout(300, function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

html:

```
            <table>
                <tr><td style="vertical-align: top;"><div id="shoutdate">
                    <div id="time"><?=$date;?><br><?=$time?></div>
                </div></td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;"><div id="shoutby">
                    <div id="poster"><a href="?l=profile&id=<?=$poster;?>" id="<?=$rank;?>"><?=$poby;?></a></div>
                </div></td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;"><div id="shoutcon">
                    <?=$message?>
                    <? /* if ($ctrl == 1){ */?>
                        <div id="admin">
                            <div id="ban"></div>
                            <a href="" id="<?=$sht_id;?>" class="delete"><div id="del"></div></a>
                        </div>
                    <?/* } */?>
                </div></td></tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you will want to use the `success` function (spelled correctly). Also `$(this)` had to be changed otherwise it would call `$(this)` of success.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".delete").click(function(){
        var element = $(this);
        var sht_id = element.attr("id");
        var info = 'id=' + sht_id;
        $this = $(this);
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'delsht.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: info,
                success: function() {
                   $this.parents(".item").fadeout(300, function(){
                      $this.remove();
                   });
                }
            });

        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

`update:`

give your table a class of `item` and change the Parent part

Comment: oky, i did as u said, it doesn't refresh anymore, tough it still won't do any animation, i need to refresh manually now to see if the record has been deleted... kind regards

Comment: I updated my answer: give the table a class and change your parent parent part.

Comment: tnx for the help, tough there's still no animation, and i'll leave it that way. My example page will be used inside an ajax livefeed. i got rid of the page refresh and as for now that's the most important.
This is the result i have by now: http://178.117.173.52/r2s/

kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You are clicking in an 'a' element, so u need to prevent the default event

```
$(function () {
    $(".delete").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var _ = $(this);
        var sht_id = _.attr("id");
        var info = 'id=' + sht_id;
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'delsht.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: info,
                succes: function() {
                    _.closest('tr').remove();
                }
            });

        }
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: same result as above answer... script still deletes, does not refresh anymore but still no animation so i need to refresh manually to see if the record has been deleted

Comment: You can try pick the closest "tr" and remove   _.closest('tr').remove()
Try whitout the fade for test

Comment: Try put the jquery-ui for animations, probably that's the animation problem

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have your delete button enclosed in a "a href" tag as jquery will handle a div being clicked. Change the

```
<a href="" id="<?=$sht_id;?>" class="delete"><div id="del"></div></a>
```

to read

```
<div id="<?=$sht_id;?>" class="delete"><div id="del"></div></div>
```

I think the

```
<a href=""
```

is what is causing the page to reload

Comment: first i had <a href="#" as shown in multiple examples i've followed, but didn't like to see the # appear in the url. so i deleted it. tough it gives the same result